# EndPoint Basic Auth vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Estoy intentando consumir un end point con basic Auth con vue.js pero me tira error. Éste es el código que estoy utilizando:

```
let user ='user';
  let pswd = 'pass'
  const encodedUserPswd = btoa(`${user}:${pswd}`);
  axios.get( "https://api.alegra.com/api/v1/sellers/", {
    headers: {'Authorization: Basic ${encodedUserPswd}'}
  })
  .then(response =>{
      console.log(response.data )
     // this.todos = response.data
  })
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te *tira*? Te recomiendo completar el [tour] de bienvenida para aprender más sobre qué se considera una pregunta bien planteada y por qué es importante tratar de mostrar un [mcve]

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que el método debe ser **GET** y no un **POST**? Adicionalmente, intenta cambiar tu objeto headers por un objeto válido: `{headers: {'Authorization': `Basic ${encodedUserPwd}`}}`. Otra observación es que estás haciendo uso de [plantillas literales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) en un string que no está delimitado por ` \`\` `